# IndexError: list index out of range [Tensorflow 1.5 & Python 3.6]

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently, I'm working on implementing code in "Differentially Private Federated Learning: A Client Level Perspective" where the GitHub link is [LINK](https://github.com/SAP-samples/machine-learning-diff-private-federated-learning.git). However, I followed the instruction but got an error which is

```
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/machine-learning-diff-private-federated-learning-main/Helper_Functions.py", line 217, in load_from_directory_or_initialize
Accuracy_accountant = Lines[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The part of the code is

```
if os.path.isfile(directory + '/specs.csv'):
  with open(directory + '/specs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
      reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      Lines = []
      for line in reader:
          Lines.append([float(j) for j in line])

      Accuracy_accountant = Lines[-1]
      Delta_accountant = Lines[1]
```

I don't think there's an error. I'm using Tensorflow 1.5 and python 3.6.
Feel free the check the code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13cdUliwze92fYVOZbxTNLmUtcOWfJLPk/view?usp=sharing). Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: This indicates that `Lines` is an empty list - are you sure it's populated?

Comment: I think the issue is your indentation in line no. 2 after if os.path.isfile(directory + '/specs.csv'):

Comment: @HarshGupta that just seems to be an issue with copying the code from the link - if it was an indentation error this snippet wouldn't even run.

Comment: I suspect the issue is bc I'm using python3.x but this code was written in python 2.x, it should be related to ascii & utf-8. Can anyone tell me how I can change this? Many thanks!

Comment: For this specific piece of code, it doesn't seem like it would be an ASCII/UTF-8 issue. If you run a script with this particular code only (and nothing else), do you get the problem? Can you show a couple lines from the `specs.csv` file this is trying to read? I'm assuming it's actually an empty file.

Comment: Yes, specs.csv is empty, but idk why..weird.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `open()` method and make your own `csv` directory file `(example: path=directory + '/specs.csv' )`
The problem is from `reader`, I think `reader` is empty so `Lines` will be empty and it will give you that error.
Instead, try this:

```
csvfile = directory + '/specs.csv'
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
Lines = []
for line in reader:
      Lines.append([float(j) for j in line])

Accuracy_accountant = Lines[-1]
Delta_accountant = Lines[1]
```

Comment: still not working, I find csv file is empty but Idk why..it generated error of "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '/'"

Comment: @YiEric check the csv file, if the reader is empty, the problem is from reader. maybe add 'specs.csv' to your path, copy the full path and paste in csvfile, for example: csvfile = 'C:/user/.../specs.csv'
reader should not be empty.
`"ValueError: could not convert string to float: '/'" `: This means you cannot convert " / " to a number

use Pandas to read csv file:

Answer (score -3):

```
import pandas as pd

csvfile = 'specs.csv'
reader = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
Lines = []
for line in reader:
      Lines.append([float(j) for j in line])

Accuracy_accountant = Lines[-1]
Delta_accountant = Lines[1]
```

Comment: OP is asking a specific question about their code. How does a completely separate code snippet help? What did you change, and why?

Comment: @Chris I just used a simle method to get a csv file, which is pandas, the problem may be because of open(file) method

Comment: Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure your answers actually address the question being asked.